# Why won't my \mathrlap stay overlapping?

Tags: symbols, mathtools, amssymb, overlap

I've defined a `\boxstar` command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\boxstar}{\mathrlap{\boxplus}\boxtimes}
```

This looks quite nice on its own.

[image]

However, when I have a line of boxstars and other symbols, the boxstars stop overlapping properly.

```
$$\boxstar \boxstar \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes $$
```

[image]

What's going on here?

(Using `amssymb` and `mathtools`.)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you show us some minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Never use `$$` in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

When you do `\boxstar \boxstar \boxtimes \boxtimes` you have the following sequence of atoms, due to the fact that your `\boxstar` is composed by an ordinary symbol (O) followed by a binary operation (B):

> O (m) B (m) O (m) B (m) B (0) B

TeX will insert a medium space (m) where indicated, but zero space between the two last B's, because they are incompatible with binary operations, so they're treated as O.

How do you solve the issue? By stating how the new symbol should behave and using braces around `\boxtimes` so it effectively becomes an ordinary symbol:

```
\newcommand{\boxstar}{\mathbin{\mathrlap{\boxplus}{\boxtimes}}}
```

The braces are not really needed here, because a subformula consisting of OB will become OO (by the same rules mentioned above), but is conceptually better to have them.

This works because `\boxplus` and `\boxtimes` have the same width. In order to superimpose symbols with different widths, the simplest method is to exploit `\ooalign`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427 for a quick course on it.

Your example

```
\[
\boxstar \boxstar \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes
\]
```

will now become

> B B B B B B B

that's transformed into

> O (m) B (m) O (m) B (m) O (m) B (m) O

because of incompatible BB sequences.

Answer (score 3):

You have to group the two symbols together.  Here I do this using `\mathbin` to indicate to TeX, that `\boxstar` is a binary operator.  If you fail to do this, the spacing around `\boxtimes` is influenced by the symbol following after it which makes the `\boxplus` go off center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\boxstar}{\mathbin{\mathrlap{\boxplus}\boxtimes}}
\begin{document}
\[ \boxstar \boxstar \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend to overlay symbols using `\ooalign`, because this overlays them with respect to the center (`\mathrlap` overlay with respect to the left boundary).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\boxstar{\mathpalette\@boxstar\relax}
\newcommand*\@boxstar[2]{%
  \mathbin{%
    \ooalign{%
      $\m@th#1\boxplus$\cr
      \hidewidth$\m@th#1\boxtimes$\hidewidth\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \boxstar \boxstar \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \boxtimes \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much appreciated. But your `\ooalign` example is quite beyond me: could you explain briefly what the parameter is for, why you go in and out of math mode, etc?

Comment: @Draconis I use `\mathpalette` to forward the surrounding mathstyle into `\ooalign` (that is `#1`), the second parameter is just `\relax` and therefore unused.  I have to reenter math mode inside the `\ooalign` because it actually a text mode macro.