# How to create symbol "cross product with dot under it"

Tags: times, math-fonts

[image: *enter image description here*]

Is there any package with that symbol circled in orange in the photo? Thanks for answering.

Comment: What does this symbol mean?  If it's that rare that Tex doesn't have it, it means Knuth never used it, so the rest of us don't know what it means either.  Why do you want to use it?

Comment: @DDuck That book is written in Tex so it must exist. We are using that symbol for Cartesian product of two semialgebras.

Comment: Did you look in http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427) (one of my favorite toys) together with [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/4427) for properly scaling the symbol if in subscripts or superscripts. Note that the dot is properly centered, contrary to what the image shows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\timesdot}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\timesdot@\relax}}
\newcommand{\timesdot@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\times$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1.$\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{I}\timesdot\mathcal{J}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\timesdot{\stackMath\mathbin{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{-0.49ex}{\scriptscriptstyle.}{\times}}}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal I \timesdot \mathcal J$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If larger space is also OK:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{180}{$\dottimes$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Observe that the dot is not inside the times.

Comment: @Sigur Sure, that's why I make the if case for larger space

Comment: Also, try to insert those 2 letters around it, as OP had shown.