# Strike out an arrow with a small oblique segment like with \nrightarrow

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, strikeout

I'm looking for a way to strike out an arrow in the same style (or idiscernible) as predefined struck arrows, with short, slightly-oblique segments, like for instance `\nrightarrow`. Using `\not` or `\cancel` unfortunately yields awful results.

Comment: Which kind of arrow would you like to strike out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## New answer (better)

I've come up with a better way to do this. Because the slash created by `\not` is too long I'm using rotated versions of shorter horizontal lines instead. I'm doing this rather than scaling the slash created by `\not` to match the thickness of the original line (without spoiling the round caps).

I'm defining four macros below that cross out a relational symbol:

- `\Neg[<shift>]{<symbol>}` just uses `\not`;
- `\sNeg[<shift>]{<symbol>}` uses a rotated `-`;
- `\ssNeg[<shift>]{<symbol>}` uses two rotated `\dabar@`s;
- `\sssNeg[<shift>]{<symbol>}` uses one rotated `\dabar@`;

`\Neg` matches the slash produced by `\not`, `\sNeg` matches that in `\nRightarrow`, `\ssNeg` matches that in `\nrightarrow` and `\sssNeg` just creates a really short slash.
If an optional argument is provided the slash will be shifted to the right by this amount. Note however that `<shift>` is a length in `mu`, so it has to be of the form `<number>mu` (N.B. `18mu` is equal to `1em`, except it scales in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`).

(*The character produced by `\dabar@` is a short horizontal rule (with rounded ends) that is (I think) only used in the definition of `\dashrightarrow`. I wanted to use `\shortmid`, but this character isn't vertically centred (which means I would have to manually adjust its vertical position).*)

This code produces an (incomplete) list of negated arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}  %% <- for some of the arrows
\usepackage{graphicx} %% <- for \rotatebox

\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command names
\newcommand*\Neg[2][0mu]{\Neginternal{#1}{\negslash}{#2}}
\newcommand*\sNeg[2][0mu]{\Neginternal{#1}{\snegslash}{#2}}
\newcommand*\ssNeg[2][0mu]{\Neginternal{#1}{\ssnegslash}{#2}}
\newcommand*\sssNeg[2][0mu]{\Neginternal{#1}{\sssnegslash}{#2}}
\newcommand*\Neginternal[3]{\mathpalette\Neg@{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand*\Neg@[2]{\Neg@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand*\Neg@@[4]{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1#4$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#3{#1}\mkern\muexpr#2*2$\hidewidth\cr
  }}%
}

\newcommand*\negslash[1]{\m@th#1\not\mathrel{\phantom{=}}}
\newcommand*\snegslash[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{60}{$\m@th#1-$}}
\newcommand*\ssnegslash[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{60}{$\m@th#1{\dabar@}\mkern-7mu{\dabar@}$}}
\newcommand*\sssnegslash[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{60}{$\m@th#1\dabar@$}}
\makeatother  %% <- revert @

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{cccccc}
        \texttt{\tiny\textbackslash not}&
        \texttt{\tiny\textbackslash Neg}&
        \texttt{\tiny\textbackslash sNeg}&
        \texttt{\tiny\textbackslash ssNeg}&
        \texttt{\tiny\textbackslash sssNeg}&
        \texttt{\tiny\textbackslash n<arrow>}
        \\\hline
        \not\rightarrow & \Neg[1mu]{\rightarrow} & \sNeg[1mu]{\rightarrow} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\rightarrow} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\rightarrow} & \nrightarrow
        \\
        \not\leftarrow & \Neg[-1mu]{\leftarrow} & \sNeg[-1mu]{\leftarrow} & \ssNeg[-1mu]{\leftarrow} & \sssNeg[-1mu]{\leftarrow} & \nleftarrow
        \\
        \not\Rightarrow & \Neg[2mu]{\Rightarrow} & \sNeg[2mu]{\Rightarrow} & \ssNeg[2mu]{\Rightarrow} & \sssNeg[2mu]{\Rightarrow} & \nRightarrow
        \\
        \not\leftrightarrow & \Neg{\leftrightarrow} & \sNeg{\leftrightarrow} & \ssNeg{\leftrightarrow} & \sssNeg{\leftrightarrow} & \nleftrightarrow
        \\
        \not\Leftrightarrow & \Neg{\Leftrightarrow} & \sNeg{\Leftrightarrow} & \ssNeg{\Leftrightarrow} & \sssNeg{\Leftrightarrow} & \nLeftrightarrow
        \\
        \not\mapsto & \Neg[1mu]{\mapsto} & \sNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\mapsto}
        \\
        \not\hookrightarrow & \Neg[1mu]{\hookrightarrow} & \sNeg[1mu]{\hookrightarrow} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\hookrightarrow} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\hookrightarrow}
        \\
        \not\leadsto & \Neg[1mu]{\leadsto} & \sNeg[1mu]{\leadsto} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\leadsto} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\leadsto}
        \\
        \not\rightsquigarrow & \Neg[1mu]{\rightsquigarrow} & \sNeg[1mu]{\rightsquigarrow} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\rightsquigarrow} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\rightsquigarrow}
        \\
        \not\rightharpoonup & \Neg[1mu]{\rightharpoonup} & \sNeg[1mu]{\rightharpoonup} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\rightharpoonup} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\rightharpoonup}
        \\
        \not\rightarrowtail & \Neg[1mu]{\rightarrowtail} & \sNeg[1mu]{\rightarrowtail} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\rightarrowtail} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\rightarrowtail}
        \\
        \not\rightrightarrows & \Neg[1mu]{\rightrightarrows} & \sNeg[1mu]{\rightrightarrows} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\rightrightarrows} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\rightrightarrows}
        \\
        \not\longrightarrow & \Neg[1mu]{\longrightarrow} & \sNeg[1mu]{\longrightarrow} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\longrightarrow} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\longrightarrow}
        \\
        \not\xrightarrow{abcdefg} & \Neg[1mu]{\xrightarrow{abcdefg}} & \sNeg[1mu]{\xrightarrow{abcdefg}} & \ssNeg[1mu]{\xrightarrow{abcdefg}} & \sssNeg[1mu]{\xrightarrow{abcdefg}}
    \end{array}
\]

\[
    x \Neg[1mu]{\mapsto} y_{x \Neg[1mu]{\mapsto} y_{x \Neg[1mu]{\mapsto} y}},
    x \sNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y_{x \sNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y_{x \sNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y}},
    x \ssNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y_{x \ssNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y_{x \ssNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y}},
    x \sssNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y_{x \sssNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y_{x \sssNeg[1mu]{\mapsto} y}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

#### A few notes

- I capitalised `\Neg` because `\neg` already exists (it produces a "¬").
- I'm using [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/156366) to ensure that the symbol scales properly in sub-/superscripts etc.
- I'm using `\ooalign` (cf. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/156366)) to superimpose `\not\mathrel{\phantom{=}}` and these arrows.
- I'm using `\rotatebox` from [`graphicx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) to rotate horizontal lines by 60º. You can change this number if you want.
- The `\phantom{=}` in `\negslash` is necessary because while `\not` itself has no width, it is (I believe) designed to match the width of the `=` character.

(*Digression: It's kind of odd that `\nrightarrow` has a significantly smaller arrowhead than `\rightarrow`, and the same is true for a couple of the other `amssymb` arrows. I've personally never really liked the rather wide arrowheads of the Computer Modern maths font, so it would've been nice if they had also included a version of `\rightarrow` with a smaller head.*)

## Old answer (obsolete)

In my old answer I superimposed a `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` slash on top of the arrow. The result didn't look as good and didn't work in e.g. sub-/superscripts. It worked the same otherwise.

```
\newcommand*\negrel[3][0mu]{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{%
    $#3$\cr
    \hidewidth$\vcenter{\hbox{$#2\not\mathrel{\phantom{=}}$}}\mkern\muexpr#1*2$\hidewidth
    \cr
  }}%
}
\newcommand*\sneg[2][0mu]{\negrel[#1]{\scriptstyle}{#2}}
\newcommand*\ssneg[2][0mu]{\negrel[#1]{\scriptscriptstyle}{#2}}
```