# How to get uneven size/space of numerator and denominator in fraction enclosed by \left\{ and \right} brackets

Tags: spacing, brackets, fractions

The following code gives a large amount of space under the denominator, enclosed by the left and right brackets, \left{ and \right}:

```
U_{ij}^{\mathrm{tor}}(\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{ij},\mathbf{\Omega}_i,\mathbf{\Omega}_j) = 
\exp \left\{ - \frac {\left[ \underset{\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}}{\min} \left( \phi_{\alpha\beta}-\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta} \right) \right] ^{2}} {2\sigma_{\mathrm{tor}}^{2}} \right\}
```

[image: Equation code output]

I do not want this space. I do not mind if the denominator is smaller than the numerator. How can I achieve this? (It would be nice if the fraction bar was in line with the equals sign, but I do not really mind.)

(I have tried manually sizing the brackets, but can't get any big enough.)

Comment: (1) welcome , (2) Fences are always symmetric  around the center math axis (approx the vertical middle of =). Note that since your are using `{}` as your fences, there is no reason to scale them this big, even in smaller sizes it is clear what the `{}` fence in. (3) I would how ever rewrite this and pull the fraction out front, then the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way to accomplish what you want. It is a little involved, but it seems to generally work well as long as the wrapped expression has at least a certain height/depth. It may however require some more testing and can probably be made more efficient.

I'm defining `\unevenbrace` and `\unevenbrack` below.
Both take one argument and wrap it in unbalanced braces or brackets respectively, as requested.
Note that everything scales properly when these macros are used in sub-/superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{trimclip} %% <- for \clipbox

\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command names
\newcommand*\unevendelim[3]{{\mathpalette\unevendelim@{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}}
\def\unevendelim@#1#2{\unevendelim@@{#1}#2}%
\def\unevendelim@@#1#2#3#4{%
    \sbox0{$\m@th#1#4$}%
    \sbox6{$\m@th#1\{\}$}%
    \unevendelim@@@{#1}{\left#2}{\right.}%
    \copy0
    \unevendelim@@@{#1}{\left.}{\right#3}%
}
\def\unevendelim@@@#1#2#3{%
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1#2\rule{0pt}{\ht0}#3$}%
  \sbox4{$\m@th#1#2\rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dp0}#3$}%
  \ifdim\ht2>\ht4
    \ooalign{\clipbox{0pt {\dimexpr\dp2-\dp6\relax} 0pt 0pt}{\copy2}\cr
             \raisebox{-\dp6}{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt {\dimexpr2\ht2-\ht4+\dp6}}{\copy2}}\cr}
  \else
    \ooalign{\raisebox{\ht6}{\clipbox{0pt {\dimexpr2\dp4-\dp2+\ht6} 0pt 0pt}{\copy4}}\cr
             \clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt {\dimexpr\ht4-\ht6}}{\copy4}\cr}
  \fi
}
\makeatother  %% <- revert @

% \newcommand*\unevenparen{\unevendelim()}   %% <- looks AWFUL
\newcommand*\unevenbrace{\unevendelim\{\}}
\newcommand*\unevenbrack{\unevendelim[]}

\begin{document}

\[
    U_{ij}^{\mathrm{tor}}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{ij},\mathbf{\Omega}_i,\mathbf{\Omega}_j)
      = \exp\unevenbrace{
          - \frac{ \unevenbrack{
                     \min\limits_{\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}}
                       (\phi_{\alpha\beta}-\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta} )
                   }^{2}
                 }{2\sigma_{\mathrm{tor}}^{2}}
             }
\]
\[
    U_{ij}^{\mathrm{tor}}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{ij},\mathbf{\Omega}_i,\mathbf{\Omega}_j)
      = \exp\unevenbrace{
          - \frac{2\sigma_{\mathrm{tor}}^{2}
                 }{ \unevenbrack{
                      \min\limits^{\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}}
                        (\phi_{\alpha\beta}-\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta} )
                    }^{2}
                  }
             }
\]
\[
    e^{e^{\exp\unevenbrace{
          - \frac{ \unevenbrack{
                     \min\limits_{\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}}
                       (\phi_{\alpha\beta}-\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta} )
                   }^{2}
                 }{2\sigma_{\mathrm{tor}}^{2}}
          }
    }}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

These commands work by stitching together different parts of the braces/brackets produced with `\left` and `\right` using `\clipbox`. It doesn't work for parentheses because these don't have a straight part where this suture can be applied unnoticed.

---

### Really quick explanation

Here's what happens, step by step:

1. [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/156366) is used to get the math style (display/text/script/scriptscript) right.
2. `<expr>` is typeset in the right style in box register `0`;
3. `\{\}` is similarly typeset in box register `6`, just so we can determine its height/depth (which feels a little gratuitous).
4. `\left\{<something as tall as <expr>>\right.` is typeset in box `2`.
5. `\left.<something as deep as <expr>>\right\}` is typeset in box `4`.
6. If box `2` is taller, then its top half should be drawn, along with however much is needed from the bottom to reach the depth of box `4`. The "top half" is defined as everything above the *depth* of box `6`.
7. If box `4` is taller, then its bottom half should be drawn, along with however much is needed from the top to reach the height of box `2`. The "bottom half" is defined as everything below the *height* of box `6`.
8. `\clipbox` is used to cut up box `2` and box `4`. This command is defined by the [`trimclip`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.pdf) package, which is part of [`adjustbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox).
9. `\raisebox` is used to get the vertical positioning right.
10. [`\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/156366) is used to splice these cuttings together.
11. The contents of box `0` (which was `<expr>`) is printed.
12. Steps 4–10 are repeated for the right brace.

Comment: Beware that there are some limitations though: this won't work for a pair of braces that should have the normal size on one end.

Answer (score 1):

A main cause for the growth of the size is the subscript to `\min`.

I propose two variations and one more proposed by daleif in comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Definitely ugly
\[
U_{ij}^{\mathrm{tor}}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{ij},\mathbf{\Omega}_i,\mathbf{\Omega}_j) = 
\exp \left\{ 
  - \frac{\left[
            \min\limits_{\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}}
            \left(
              \phi_{\alpha\beta}-\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}
            \right)
          \right] ^{2}
         }{2\sigma_{\mathrm{tor}}^{2}}
\right\}
\]

Possibly better
\[
U_{ij}^{\mathrm{tor}}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{ij},\mathbf{\Omega}_i,\mathbf{\Omega}_j) = 
\exp \Biggl\{ 
  - \frac{\Bigl[\,
            \min_{\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}}
            (\phi_{\alpha\beta}-\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta})
          \Bigr] ^{2}
         }{2\sigma_{\mathrm{tor}}^{2}}
\Biggl\}
\]

Good?
\[
U_{ij}^{\mathrm{tor}}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{ij},\mathbf{\Omega}_i,\mathbf{\Omega}_j) = 
\exp \biggl\{ 
  - \biggl[
      \min\limits_{\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}}
      (\phi_{\alpha\beta}-\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta})
    \biggr] ^{2}
    \bigg/
    (2\sigma_{\mathrm{tor}}^{2})
\biggl\}
\]

Daleif proposal
\[
U_{ij}^{\mathrm{tor}}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{ij},\mathbf{\Omega}_i,\mathbf{\Omega}_j) = 
\exp \biggl\{ 
  - \frac{1}{2\sigma_{\mathrm{tor}}^{2}}
\biggl[
      \min\limits_{\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta}}
      (\phi_{\alpha\beta}-\phi^{\mathrm{offset}}_{\alpha\beta})
    \biggr] ^{2}
\biggl\}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why not just `-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2_{\mathrm{tor}}}\Bigl[...`?

Comment: @daleif Another possibility, right.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I would have been fine with one of these simpler alternatives

Comment: @CampanIgnis The “possibly better” method allows for the minus sign to be in either part, but it's a bit unnatural. If the minus sign is in front of the fraction brackets are necessary.