# Drawing absolute value bars around a fraction with different height of numerator and denominator

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, vertical-spacing, bigdelim

I would like to typeset the absolute value of a fraction, e. g.

[image]

with absolute value bars that are shorter at the bottom, like in

[image]

Is there any way in LaTeX to achieve this rather than the first example?

#### Details:

I am calculating the angle between two lines in three-dimensional space with the following formula:

[image]

This looks really nice. But when I now substitute the coordinates of the vectors like this:

```
\cos\phi=\left|\frac{
        \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
    \circ
        \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}
    }{
        \sqrt3\cdot\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}
    }\right|
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Yuck! There is way too much space below the fraction inside the absoulte value bars!

I already tried using `\Biggl|` and `\Biggr`:

```
\cos\phi=\Biggl|\frac{
        \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
    \circ
        \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}
    }{
        \sqrt3\cdot\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}
    }\Biggr|
```

but that only yields a somewhat acceptable, but slightly incorrect result:

[image]

Comment: Related and probably adaptable: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472540/134144

Comment: Unrelated: what is the composition of two vectors?

Comment: In Bavarian (German?) schools, we use \circ as the symbol for the scalar product. I don't know why - we could as well use < . >, but for some reason we don't.

Comment: @leandriis: That's really interesting - I already know I will come back for those funny asymmetric braces one day! But for something as simple as vertical bars I prefer Steven's answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, I use `\stretchleftright{|}{...}{|}` to achieve it.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{scalerel,amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\[
\cos\phi=\stretchleftright{|}{\frac{
        \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
    \circ
        \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}
    }{
        \sqrt3\cdot\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}
    }}{|} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well .. this is simply great, thanks! And I noticed that \stretchleftright works for ( [ \{ \} ] ) as well!

Comment: @Iziminza Yes, it works for any glyph, but BEWARE, by stretching a `[`, the vertical line stays the same, but the horizontal lines thicken (ugh).  The result is more presentable for parens than brackets.  p.s. There is also a `\scaleleftright` to scale rather than stretch the delimiters.  You should also look into their optional arguments, which can be of use, as well.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to suggest a solution that's different from either of your preferred choices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
\cos\phi= \frac{1}{\sqrt3 \cdot\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}}
          \abs*{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\circ
                \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}}  
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I could have also put the absolute value bars around the numerator alone. But our textbook puts the whole fraction inside them, so I prefer the other solution in order not to confuse my students.