# Typing Specific Inequality Symbol

Tags: symbols, amsmath, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

I'm trying to type the following symbol in TeX, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Am I supposed to create it myself? If so, how should I do this? Please and thank you.

[image]

Comment: What does this symbol mean?

Comment: Would ⋛ (`\gtreqless`) or ⋚ (`\lesseqgtr`) from `univode-math`, `stix`, etc. meet your needs? Or the many other variants such as ⪑ or ⪓?

Comment: If not, you could overlay `\geq` and `\le` with `\@ooalign`.

Comment: Or add an underbar to ⪤ `\glj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could indeed construct it yourself by printing a `\leq` symbol on a `\geq` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\leqgeq}{%
    \mathrel{\mathpalette\@leqgeq\relax}%
}
\newcommand*{\@leqgeq}[2]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\(#1\leq\)}\mbox{\(#1\geq\)}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
if \( a \leqgeq b \)

\(\displaystyle a \leqgeq b\)
\(\textstyle a \leqgeq b\)
\(\scriptstyle a \leqgeq b\)
\(\scriptscriptstyle a \leqgeq b\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you generalize this command to let it operate correctly in subscript or superscript positions?

Comment: @Mico Like this?

Comment: Yes, `\mathpalette` gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

An easy application of [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/4427) (for taking into account the current math style) and [`\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427) (for superimposing two symbols).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\win}{% weird inequality
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\win@\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\win@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\leq$\cr$\m@th#1\geq$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\win b$

$\scriptstyle a\win b$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\win b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Before you ask a new question, here's how to cope also with < and >.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\win}{% weird inequality
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\win@{<>}}%
}
\newcommand{\wineq}{% weird inequality
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\win@{\leq\geq}}%
}
\newcommand{\win@}[2]{\win@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\win@@}[3]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1#2$\cr$\m@th#1#3$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\win b\wineq c$

$\scriptstyle a\win b\wineq c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\win b\wineq c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(edited the solution to permit it to work in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` situations)

Here's a solution which employs the TeX primitives `\hss` and `\cr` and the low-level command `\ooalign` to superimpose the `\ge` and `\le` symbols and which employs a `\mathchoice directive to permit typesetting the symbol in first- and second-order sub/superscript mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\funkyneq{\mathrel{\mathchoice
    {\ooalign{\hss$\ge$\cr$\le$}}
    {\ooalign{\hss$\ge$\cr$\le$}}
    {\ooalign{\hss$\scriptstyle\ge$\cr$\scriptstyle\le$}}
    {\ooalign{\hss$\scriptscriptstyle\ge$\cr$\scriptscriptstyle\le$}}
}}
\begin{document}
$a\funkyneq b \quad \scriptstyle 
 a\funkyneq b \quad \scriptscriptstyle 
 a\funkyneq b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite a mouthful!

Comment: @egreg - `\win` is definitely a more memorable name than `\funkyneq`....

Answer (score 1):

```
\tracinglostchars = 2 % Warn if a glyph is missing from a font
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagestyle{empty}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\newcommand\glej{\mathrel{\underline{\glj}}}

\begin{document}
\[ a \glej b \]
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two Font Sample]

To get just this one symbol from STIX Two Math, use `\setmathfont[range=\glj, Scale=MatchLowercase]{STIX Two Math}` instead.

If you need to use PDFLaTeX instead, the `\glj` symbol is in the `stix` and `stix2` packages.