How does one create a symbol that is an $\infty$, centred and superimposed on a $0$, with the appropriate width?
A MathStackExchange comment by pregunton pointed out a paper Brinsfield - The factoradic integers, and mentioned an unusual symbol used in Definition 19 on logical p. 29 (the 34th page of the document):

The symbol seems to be an $\infty$, centred and superimposed on a $0$.  I naïvely tried \mathclap\infty0, which, if you know \mathclap, you will know doesn't work, so it occurred to me to try \mathclap\infty\mathclap0.  This looks right but has zero width, as it should, as indicated in the picture below by actually typesetting [\mathclap\infty\mathclap0].  Eventually all I could come up with was \hspace{\widthof{\(\infty\)}/2}\mathclap\infty\mathclap0\hspace{\widthof{\(\infty\)}/2}, which works as long as it is used inline, but is awful.  It seems that I must just be overlooking the obvious correct way to do this.  What is it?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\(\mathclap\infty0\)

\([\mathclap\infty\mathclap0]\)

\([\hspace{\widthof{\(\infty\)}/2}\mathclap\infty\mathclap0\hspace{\widthof{\(\infty\)}/2}]\)
\end{document}



Honestly all of this looks really messy. One problem is that the infinity symbol has an antiqua-style weight axis while the zero is modern / didone style. Mashing them together will always look just like what it is: two separate symbols mashed together. I'd consider whether some kind of trefoil symbol could be used instead.

@leftaroundabout, re, thank you for the interesting perspective.  Certainly one can discuss whether this is a good symbol to use, and should if its use is to be perpetuated; but, since I don't intend to use it, I didn't pursue that line of inquiry.  I was just viewing it as a purely TeXnical problem: someone out there did produce this symbol; how?  (Now ably answered by @‍egreg, though, given the improved spacing of their version over the original, it's probably not how the original was done.)

Al;so \mathmakebox[\widthof{\infty}][c]{\mathclap{0}\mathclap{\infty}}.

ooalign is your friend. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/4427 for more information.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\brinsfield}{}{\mathord{\mathpalette\brinsfield@\relax}}
\newcommand{\brinsfield@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1 0$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\infty$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

We define $\brinsfield\brinsfield=\brinsfield$,
$\brinsfield+\brinsfield=\brinsfield$

We can use it also in subscripts: $A_{\brinsfield}$

\end{document}


Note that the spacing is even better than in the original.
A possible improvement:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\brinsfield}{}{\vphantom{0}\mathord{\mathpalette\brinsfield@\relax}}
\newcommand{\brinsfield@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1 0$}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\usebox\z@\hidewidth\cr
    \raisebox{\dimeval{(\ht\z@-\height)/2}}{$\m@th#1\infty$}\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

We define $\brinsfield\brinsfield=\brinsfield$,
$\brinsfield+\brinsfield=\brinsfield$

We can use it also in subscripts: $A_{\brinsfield}$

\end{document}



Thanks; I'd never heard of \ooalign!  I'm also still a bit hazy on \mathpalette.  I think that I understand where \brinsfield@ is getting its two arguments, but what is the macro \m@th?

@LSpice \m@th removes the \mathsurround, which is usually zero, but one never knows. I added a possible improvement of the symbol.

Re, thanks!

@LSpice I simplified the code for the improved symbol.
