# How to reduce spacing in equations?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to typeset short equations (variable = value) saving space.

Is there a **global parameter** which allows to reduce the space between operators and operands in math mode?

---

I found out, that there is a negative space `\!`which could be used, but I would have to type it in each single equation, which is inefficient.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
$a_0\!\!=\!\!12{,}459$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not only is using `\!` inefficient: you shouldn't use it around binary operations or relations since it can lead to very bad spacing; see e.g. [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14214).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$a_0{=}12{,}459$

\thickmuskip=0.5\thickmuskip
$a_0=12{,}459$

\thickmuskip=0mu
$a_0=12{,}459$
```

from Typographer's view: it is not a good idea ...

Comment: thanks! I agree that the standard spacing makes sense, but I have to deal with a large matrix of graphs where lateral space is a serious problem. I do want to use that only in those graphs.  However, your solution is more elegant then `\!\!=` but also "local" and no global option. And maybe there could be a compromise which half of the standard space (as a global option)?

Comment: @Martin: you can decrease `\thickmuskip` for a global setting, see edited answer

Answer (score 3):

If *all* of your math is of this form then you can think of reducing the space; but it's not a good idea, in my opinion.

I suggest a different approach than redefining globally the spacing around relation symbols:

```
\newcommand{\seq}{\,{=}\,} % special equals
```

so that, if you change your mind, it's just a matter of changing this into

```
\newcommand{\seq}{=}
```