# Changing the spacing inside equation with underbrace

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am aware of questions/answers that address the question of space around the equal-sign (e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36647/how-to-reduce-spacing-in-equations) or [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41913/how-to-get-less-spacing-in-math-mode)).
However, my question is related to a situation where I make use of `\underbrace`:

[image: equation with space]

The text in `\underbrace` causes a shift to the right of everything outside of the braces.
I do not want to introduce a linebreak in the text, nor do I want to extend the underbrace - I just do not like the large gap in the equation.
I have tried [`\!`](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_119.html) without significant effect.
How do I move the portion to the right of the braces so that it is partially above the text?
(Have I missed something in the [`mathtools` package documentation](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf)?)

---

This portion of code reproduces the equation above:

```
\begin{equation}  
\underbrace{\left(\frac{\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{v}}{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}\right)}_%
  {\text{projection of }\vec{\omega}\text{ on }\vec{v}}\vec{v}=%
  \frac{\xi_{\text{s}}}{v_{\text{s}}}\vec{v}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, using the `mathtools`package and its `\mathclap`command:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage{mathtools}

        \begin{document}%

        \begin{equation}
        \underbrace{\left(\frac{\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{v}}{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}\right)}%
          {\mathclap{\text{projection of }\vec{\omega}\text{ on }\vec{v}}}\vec{v}=%
          \frac{\xi_{\text{s}}}{v_{\text{s}}}\vec{v}
        \end{equation}

        \end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]