# Vain question about cdot kerning

Tags: math-mode, spacing, kerning

I'm writing my first "real" paper in Latex, and one of my major pieces of notation involves item-wise multiplying the Nx1 vector `\widehat{w}` to the Nx1 vector `\widehat{S}`, and I've been using cdot to denote the non-matrix multiplication, so basically I am writing

`(\widehat{w}\cdot\widehat{S})^{\intercal}\widetilde{H}(\widehat{w}\cdot\widehat{S})`

a million times in my paper.

I am using cdot to avoid a lot of confusion that would result from just using `\widehat{S}_w`, or `\widehat{w}\widehat{S}` due to similar notation already in use in the paper. Basically I am complaining that the cdot adds a ton of space between the w and the S whereas really they are a single unit--a weighted S.

QUESTION: Is there any trick to shrink cdot or is there another bivariate function I could use to get the w and S to stick closer together? Can you help me make my paper prettier?

Thanks for any help.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[(\widehat{w}\cdot\widehat{S})^{\intercal}\widetilde{H}(\widehat{w}\cdot\widehat{S})\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Three suggestions:

1. See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)
2. Define a macro/command if you're using something multiple times. It promotes consistency and would make your life *much* easier if you decide to change things later on, even just a little bit. For example, `\itemmul{<mat1>}{<mat2>}`. As reference, see [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764).
3. You can modify the spacing around a relation/operator to your liking by changing it into an ordinal symbol first, and then specifying the kerning using `\mkern`. Ordinals are obtained by wrapping the relation/operator in braces, like `{\cdot}` or using `\mathord{\cdot}`. Math kerning is specified in `mu`s (or `m`ath `u`nits).

Using the above suggestions, here's a take on your spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\newcommand{\itemmul}[2]{% \itemmul{<mat1>}{<mat2>}
  \widehat{#1}\mkern1mu{\cdot}\mkern1mu\widehat{#2}% itemwise-multiplication
}
\begin{document}
\[
  (\itemmul{w}{S})^{\intercal}\widetilde{H}(\itemmul{w}{S})
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure...But in college I was told that (1) align is better than eqnarray and (2) \[ \] is better than $$ $$.

Comment: @Rebecca: Yes, `align` (requires [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) is *much* better than `eqnarray` and `\[...`\]` is preferred over `$$...$$` in LaTeX. I suggested the latter (which you haven't followed, by the way), while the former is also just a good observation in general.

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of this site (for example, I just wrote a comment but it disappeared...)

Comment: 2. I am avoiding using \renewcommand, etc. in my paper draft because it is not clear yet which journal it is going to. The 2-3 options have different rules, and I am trying to avoid trouble down the road. Honestly I think it made me better at typing in Tex, although yes it has been painful at times. 

3. Thanks for this explanation. It is much clearer than what I found when trying to answer my question with Google.

Comment: @Rebecca: If you're using `\newcommand` to create a new command that you're using "a million times", I'm sure *any* journal will accept it. If you *don't* use a new command, then you run a greater risk of not being consistent, which may be worse when writing a paper.

Comment: I've had some bad experiences in the past but it was with journals in a non-mathematical field. I'll consider a different approach for papers 2-1000. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I just checked the author information sections, and of the rather few rules they had, each of the major journals in my field included something along the lines of "Restrict the use of user-defined definitions and newcommands to the minimum." I was under the impression that this was a normal request. Is it not?

Comment: @Rebecca: Restricting it to a minimum doesn't mean you can't have any. Moreover, if the use of commands promotes consistency, I would imagine the journal would be for it, not against. Is this request normal? Sure, since they (the journal editors) eventually have to take the author document and make it conform to the regular standards, meaning they have to work with the raw code. And, if things are too cluttered with macros and personalized styles, it'll be more difficult to make it conform.

Comment: @Rebecca: The "restrict to the minimum request" is addressed at authors who start each of their papers with the same preamble containing 3000 `\newcommand`s, of which only 50 are relevant to the present paper.

Comment: @Rebecca: Also try to make your macros unique. Thus, use long names and upper case letters to avoid name clashes (with any custom macros that the publisher or other authors! might be using). Therefore, I'd recommend, `\MatrixMultiply` or something similar. Most editors will complete a macro for you, so it does not require any more typing.

Answer (score 5):

You can reduce the space in between by using  `\kern-.2em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[(\widehat{w}\!\cdot\!\widehat{S})^{\intercal}\widetilde{H}(\widehat{w}\!\cdot\!\widehat{S})\]

\[(\widehat{w}\kern-.2em\cdot\kern-.2em\widehat{S})^{\intercal}\widetilde{H}(\widehat{w}\kern-.2em\cdot\kern-.2em\widehat{S})\]
\end{document}
```

You can define a macro to make things easier.

```
\newcommand*{\mycdot}{\kern-.2em\cdot\kern-.2em}
```

The mwe is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*{\mycdot}{\kern-.2em\cdot\kern-.2em}
\begin{document}
\[(\widehat{w}\!\cdot\!\widehat{S})^{\intercal}\widetilde{H}(\widehat{w}\!\cdot\!\widehat{S})\]

\[(\widehat{w}\kern-.2em\cdot\kern-.2em\widehat{S})^{\intercal}\widetilde{H}(\widehat{w}\kern-.2em\cdot\kern-.2em\widehat{S})\]

\[(\widehat{w}\mycdot\widehat{S})^{\intercal}\widetilde{H}(\widehat{w}\mycdot\widehat{S})\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps also suggest not to use `$$...$$` in a LaTeX document and to use `\[...\]` instead?

Comment: Awesome and comprehensive answer. Thank you!

Comment: I don't actually use $$ in my doc, that was just for this question...not sure why I did that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Agreed.

Comment: @Rebecca: You are welcome. You may thank  by upvoting  answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark). This will add some reputation points to those who answered and to you. This the tradition followed here in TeX.SX.

Comment: Thanks for the introduction. I'll return to upvote. I updated my paper and it looks much better. Gracias.

Comment: @Rebecca: Welcome and thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Harish: As I have explained [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14214), it's _really_ not a good idea to use `\!` around `\cdot` and other binary operators. It would be a lot better to use something like `\newcommand*{\mycdot}{\kern.5em{\cdot}\kern.05em}`. Can you please edit your answer accordingly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HendrikVogt: In a bid to make it more general, I added it but my bad; I left the text part. Any way, here there no question of text. Hence I removed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Harish: Ah, I should have said that, too: `\kern-.2em` has all the downside that `\!` has, so nothing's really won so far. I'm sorry for bothering you!

Comment: @Harish: I'm sorry too keep nagging, but your answer really has a serious drawback. [Look what can happen!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/faod0.png) Here's the code: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\mycdot}{\kern-.2em\cdot\kern-.2em}
\textwidth=2.8cm
\begin{document}
$a\mycdot b$ is too \mbox{narrow}
\end{document}`

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Thanks for the feedback. `-.2em` is not a standard. It was suitable for the above case. It need not be kept same. In other words it is a variable. Hence why one will use it for all instances of `\cdot`? However, for only math cases, it is better to use `\mkern-.2mu`. I think I messed up things in an attempt to generalize the application for both text and math environments. If that is the case I feel sorry.

Comment: @Harish: Even if you use another value, I still strongly recommend not using _negative_ space around binary operations. The point is that the natural space around `\cdot` can [shrink to _zero_](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58487), and then your added negative space will cause overlaps. That's why I recommended `\newcommand*{\mycdot}{\kern.5em{\cdot}\kern.05em}`.