# Not greater than with vertical bar instead of slanted bar

Tags: math-mode, equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

When I do `$\not>$` in LaTeX it gives me [image: not greater than], however I would like the bar to vertical instead of slanted. How do I do that?

Comment: [how-to-look-up-a-symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol) and then pg 38 of `texdoc symbols` gives `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$2\ngtr 3$
\end{document}`

Comment: `\ngtr` doesn't work, beause `mathabx` clashes with another package on several symbols.

Comment: You might be interested in my comment to Boris' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, using `\rlap` to typeset bar, but not move the point?

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
$a\rlap{\kern.45em$|$}>b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work when TeX needs to stretch a line to achieve justified text: the vertical bar will move quite a bit to the left. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14214) for details.

Answer (score 13):

Overprinting symbols or text is possible `\ooalign`. The following [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) provides `\ngrt` and `\nlst` as math relations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ngrt}{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$>$\cr\hidewidth$|$\hidewidth}}%
}
\newcommand{\nlst}{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$<$\cr\hidewidth$|$\hidewidth}}%
}

\begin{document}
$a\ngrt b\nlst c$
\end{document}​
```

For a quick course in `\ooalign`, see [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).

Comment: This one is perfect. :)