# `centernot` conflict with the rest of packages

Tags: symbols

I'm gonna typeset a `NOT \ll` using the method explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14208/how-to-type-not-delta-and-not-ll) by @Leo Liu.

This code snippet that uses the minimum required packages perfectly works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
(\forall \pi_{i},\pi_{j} \in \mathcal{P}) [\pi_{i} \centernot\ll \pi_{j} \wedge \pi_{j} \centernot\ll \pi_{i}].
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

But when I use the method in my main file including many other packages, an error is thrown about `Missing $ inserted`!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[top=2cm, left = 2cm, right = 2cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
(\forall \pi_{i},\pi_{j} \in \mathcal{P}) [\pi_{i} \centernot\ll \pi_{j} \wedge \pi_{j} \centernot\ll \pi_{i}].    % error is here
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I guess there is a package conflict.

How can I fix this issue?!

Edit 1:

The error:

> Missing $ inserted. ...j} \in \mathcal{P}) [\pi_{i} \centernot\ll

Edit 2:

The conflict is with `fdsymbol` package.

Comment: Comment out packages until you make the error go away and identify the culprit that way. What else is there to do? I know robotics isn't rocket science, but .... Please provide the complete text of error messages. This will include a line number. Also, try pressing `h` for more help when you get the error.

Comment: @cfr: The problem is that I need all of those packages. The question is actually whether or not the issue can be fixed without removing any other packages.

Comment: @cfr: The error message and its location are added to the question.

Comment: The point is that you can tell us where the conflict is. We don't need a full list of everything you're loading. Find the conflict. See if the packages' manuals address it. If not, post a question about that conflict. This is all anybody can do unless they happen to know off-hand that X and Y conflict. It is just a mechanical diagnostic: you can do it as well or better than anyone else.

Comment: You can't possibly need to load packages twice. This in itself can cause problems. Also, `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so you cannot possibly need both of those. `tikz` also loads `graphicx`, though there's more of a case for listing both if you want to remind yourself or something.

Comment: @cfr: Please find edit 2.

Comment: `centernot` clash with `fdsymbol`. instead `\centernot\ll` try if `\nll` from `fdsymbol` gives satisfactory result for you and if, remove`centernot` package from preamble.

Comment: @Zarko: Thanks in advance. `\nll` saved me, and I completely got rid of `fdsymbol`. Your helpful comment is really an answer. If you add an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `fdsymbol` provides a wide range of symbols, in which many negated symbols from `amssymb` are available. Thus, package `centernot` is actually superfluous, and the clash will also be resolved.

I suggest using `\nll` from package `fdsymbol` instead of `\centernot\ll`.

Answer (score 0):

Package `centernot` assumes the original `\not`, which is a simple relational symbol. Package `fdsymbol` redefines `\not` as macro with one argument.

The patch in the following example redefines `\@centernot` to allow `\not` being a macro with one argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}

% Patch centernot to support \not as macro with argument.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@centernot{\not}{\not{\hphantom{=}}}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \noexpand\@centernot failed.}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    (\forall \pi_{i},\pi_{j} \in \mathcal{P}) [\pi_{i} \centernot\ll \pi_{j}
    \wedge \pi_{j} \centernot\ll \pi_{i}].
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Of course, using a real negated symbol as `\nll` of package `fdsymbol` as in Zarko's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387586/16967) is the preferred solution.